# Tornar o zoom da página padrão

Tags: javascript, html, zoom

Tem algum script que quando o usuario abrir o sistema o zoom ja fique pré configurado quando abrir a pagina ja fique padrão ?

Comment: Poderia elaborar um [mcve], por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A meta-tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">` **não é para todos ambientes** e em desktop talvez isso venha a não funcionar.

A propriedade `zoom: ...;` não é standard e pro isso não é suportado por todos navegadores, para que corra em todos browser atuais prefira `transform`, assim:

```
#content {
    transform: scale(2.0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
... conteudo da sua página ...
</div>
</body>
```

Não aplique diretamente no body, isso pode afetar alguns scrollbars.

Se precisar de suporte para navegadores mais antigos use:

```
#content {
    /*Safari e Chrome antigos*/
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

    /*Firefox mais antigo*/
    -moz-transform: scale(2.0);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;

    /*IE 9*/
    -ms-transform: scale(2.0);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;

    /*navegadores atualizados*/
    transform: scale(2.0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sim, e nem precisa de JS. Utilizando HTML5:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

O initial-scale controla o zoom inicial da página. 1.0 é 100%, 0.75 é 75% e assim por diante. Outra opção é utilizar a propriedade [zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) do CSS.

```
body {
    zoom: 2 /* Coloca o zoom em 200% */
}
```

Comment: vlw jovem nao estava lembrando disso ai